# @RestController with ResponseEntity is returning a body

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I created a new Spring project and deployed it in my Tomcat 7. All works fine, but when my API returns a `new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)`, Postman shows me the default 404 page error. With the same configuration it works perfectly in another Tomcat.

```java
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/users",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getUser() {
        try {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(list,HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Spring 4.3.6 and Java 1.7.0_121.

Comment: do you get any exceptions in the Tomcat log. share them it may be helpful.

Comment: The Exception throw is just an example, no mather if i directly return the NOTFOUND the result is the same, the default 404 page